# How can I execute Adobe After Effects via an EC2 Windows Server 2012 Instance?

Tags: python, iis, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, after-effects

I have an After Effects script that renders a custom video based on strings passed to it via a webpage form and some python code. It runs just fine when I execute the python code from a remote desktop connection using the administrator account. However when I try to execute it via the web page I can see that After Effects blinks on for a second in the Task Manager but it fails to output any files like it does when run as the administrator.
I'm assuming this is due to some crazy permissions issues with IIS. I've added the after effects executable directory as a virtual directory in IIS. I've also allowed the after effects executable file in the CGI restrictions. I've also set the executables folder to allow read, write, and execute permissions for the IIS-User account.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the licensing? have you considered using AERender instead of AE? Can you access the file output locations for write permissions for the IIS user? Have you looked at the AE error logs?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I turned logging on in After Effects. When I launch after effects via the python script as the administrator it starts after effects, executes the AEscript perfectly and generates a log file. When I attempt to run the python script via the web front end all aspects of the python script work fine, EXCEPT for launching after effects. It blips on in the task manager view but fails to generate a log file. This leads me to believe that After Effects isn't fully launching. Here is the python code:

Comment: p = subprocess.Popen("c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\afterFX.bat",stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
data = p.stdout.read()
p.wait()

Comment: and the batch file that executes after effects:
cd\
cd\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2014\Support Files\
afterfx.exe -noui -r c:\inetpub\wwwroot\afterFXTest.jsx

Comment: you should try dumping stdout and stderr to a file instead of the pipe to see if you pick up any additional information. I'm at a loss after that as I am not much up on windows but the contents of the afterFX.bat file might be helpful

Comment: little update: I compiled a python script into an .exe to see if it was a permissions issue. I had my python code and batch files point to the new test.exe and it worked fine. I also just copied the windows wordpad executable to the wwwroot directory and had my scripts start it. It shows up in the task manager. So it looks like its an After Effects specific issue. At this point I'm thinking it's the creative cloud app that manages the after effects license.

Comment: Figured out a much better (and more secure) solution! I have a python script running on the administrator account that watches the uploads folder. When a file is uploaded it launches after effects. Works a treat.

Comment: Hi @AdamH , I am developing a similar application with After Effect & OpenSesame Server. would it be possible to run them through PHP on EC2?